# How to make solr return spellcheck suggestions AND the search results together

Tags: solr, spell-checking, solr4

I know that `spellcheck.onlyMorePopular` flag  returns results that are more popular than the original search term , however when that happens Solr only returns the suggestions but does not include the search results for the original search terms.

How can I make it return both the things , suggestions and the search results together ? something like Google where it returns a suggestion and also results for the original term.

I think the question is if Solr actually generates  suggestions if there are any search results in first place and secondly does it return both the results and the suggestions together ?

Comment: you have to make second call to solr with the suggestion as a search term to get a result.

Comment: actually , I dont' want results for the suggested term , but results for the original term together with the suggestion , I think the question is if Solr actually generates any suggestions if there are any search results in first place and secondly does it return both the results and the suggestions together ?